# How To Create a new Ethereum Account with Mist and Nano ledger S?

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, ledger-nano-s

Intro:
In the past I managed to create 2 accounts that store the private keys in the nano ledger wallet S. I don't know how I did that.

Question:
I would like to create a new address account that stores the private key in my Nano ledger wallet. I would like doing that using just Mist/geth/nano ledger software.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

To create a second account on Ledger Nano S you can use the [passphrase or alternative PIN](https://ledger.groovehq.com/knowledge_base/topics/how-to-setup-a-passphrase-and-an-alternate-pin) feature.

Then these private keys can be viewed in a desktop wallet of your choice e.g. the official one, MyEtherWallet.